# How to get instance of the Application Class?

Tags: android, singleton

I am using a class which `extends Application` class. I have a method inside this class. I need to call this method with the help of instance. whenever I call this method using instance it throws `NullPointerException` because the instance is always null. I am using singleton pattern to obtain the instance.

### AppSetting.java

```
public class AppSetting extends Application {
    private static AppSetting instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        instance = new AppSetting();
        ....
    }

    public static synchronized AppSetting getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppSetting();
            return instance;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public somemethod() {
        return...
    }
}
```

### Activity

I am using this code to call the method `AppSetting.getInstance().somemethod()`

I always get that the instance is null. How to get the instance correctly? Am I doing anything wrong in instance creation?

Comment: Did you declare AppSetting in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @brijeshkumar its not problem , he is always initialising the `instance = new AppSetting();` if its null ! within `getInstance()` method, it can **never be null** ! @see `getInstance()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `new AppSetting()` use `this` to create instance of `AppSetting`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    instance = this;
}

public static AppSetting getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Also don't forget to add the `AppSetting` class in `AndroidManifest.xml`'s `application` tag like below:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppSetting"
    <!-- Others code -->
>
```